# Align wrapped text with text above it

Tags: html, css

In a web application I am designing, I have two columns that each contain a number of checkboxes and corresponding labels. The application is responsive and uses the Foundation web framework. On smaller screens, longer label names will wrap to the next line. I have mocked up a similar situation in the code snippets below, with the relevant styles that are on my labels and checkboxes, as provided by the stylesheet that I am working with.

Originally, I had something like this, which causes the label to be displayed on a completely separate line than the checkbox, when the screen is small enough that they can no longer fit on the same line.

```css
.container {
  width: 49.5%;
  display: inline-block;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-left .5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input id="fr_checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <label for="fr_checkbox">LONG NAME FOR LABEL THAT WILL WRAP</label>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <input id="fr_checkbox2" type="checkbox">
  <label for="fr_checkbox2">LONG NAME FOR LABEL THAT WILL WRAP</label>
</div>
```

I removed the `display: inline-block` on the label, and that helped. It will now display the label on the same line as the checkbox, then wrap any overflow to the next line.

```css
.container {
  width: 49.5%;
  display: inline-block;
}
label {
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-left .5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input id="fr_checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <label for="fr_checkbox">LONG NAME FOR LABEL THAT WILL WRAP</label>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <input id="fr_checkbox2" type="checkbox">
  <label for="fr_checkbox2">LONG NAME FOR LABEL THAT WILL WRAP</label>
</div>
```

What I would like to happen is for the label to wrap to the next line, as in the snippet above, but also line up with the text above it, rather than the left side of the container, as in the image below.

[image: intended result]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick solution for this

```css
.container {
  width: 49.5%;
  display: table;
}
label {
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-left .5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input id="fr_checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <label for="fr_checkbox">LONG NAME FOR LABEL THAT WILL WRAP</label>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <input id="fr_checkbox2" type="checkbox">
  <label for="fr_checkbox2">LONG NAME FOR LABEL THAT WILL WRAP</label>
</div>
```

Comment: +1. For the curious, it's the `display: table-cell;` part that does the wrapping and makes sure the text on subsequent lines aligns with that on the first line.